# Password protect sql database backups in maintenance plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, security, database-security

I have a microsoft sql server database (2012) and its currently being backed up using maintenance plans. I have a full back up, differential back up and transaction logs backup in my plan. For security reason i would like to add password protection on these files. Is there any way to achieve this within my maintenance plan? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this link can help: [SQL Server password protected backups](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1984/creating-sql-server-password-protected-backups-and-cleanup-tasks/)

Comment: @Chuck i believe this feature was removed in 2012.

Comment: Sorry about that, I did not know it was removed in 2012.

Comment: Make sure you have a plan to securely store your encryption key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link and it will work for me (for now at least).
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx

The following is from Microsoft Website

> Transparent Data Encryption (TDE)
>
> Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) encrypts SQL Server and Azure SQL
>   Database data files, known as encrypting data at rest. You can take
>   several precautions to help secure the database such as designing a
>   secure system, encrypting confidential assets, and building a firewall
>   around the database servers. However, in a scenario where the physical
>   media (such as drives or backup tapes) are stolen, a malicious party
>   can just restore or attach the database and browse the data. One
>   solution is to encrypt the sensitive data in the database and protect
>   the keys that are used to encrypt the data with a certificate. This
>   prevents anyone without the keys from using the data, but this kind of
>   protection must be planned in advance.
>
> TDE performs real-time I/O encryption and decryption of the data and
>   log files. The encryption uses a database encryption key (DEK), which
>   is stored in the database boot record for availability during
>   recovery. The DEK is a symmetric key secured by using a certificate
>   stored in the master database of the server or an asymmetric key
>   protected by an EKM module. TDE protects data "at rest", meaning the
>   data and log files. It provides the ability to comply with many laws,
>   regulations, and guidelines established in various industries. This
>   enables software developers to encrypt data by using AES and 3DES
>   encryption algorithms without changing existing applications.